# How to make light similar to LUMION

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How to make light similar to LUMION, Lumion uses only 1 HDRI image and not extra lights, why in blender do we need to add artificial extra lights? in exterior rendering? Anyway, to make a scene similar to Lumion just using HDRI image only and rendering in Cycles?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you don't have to use lights if you don't want to, you can use an HDRI only

Comment: I'm sorry this is a site about using Blender, not everybody knows Lumion. So would you please show us the differences? I've lit exterior scenes with 1 HDRI, you don't need to add artificial lights - depends on what you're looking for (again: not everybody knows Lumion). It's just that some people add artificial lights to have specific control on how certain parts of a scene are lit instead of relying on one magic HDRI that perfectly matches their desired outcome.